# Getting highcharts error #13 from one element rewritten as highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I created a highchart element on my page. Then I wanted to rewrite it as a highstock element. I had some errors with highstock and I couldn't get rid of them. Finally I copy-pasted highstock code from documentation but it also gives an error.

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>avra</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 SHIV -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <main>
            <a href="#">POP-UP</a>
    </main>

    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/highcharts/highstock.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data)    {
        // Create the chart
        var dataObject = {
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }],

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            }

        };

         var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(dataObject);
        //var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', dataObject);
    });
});
```

> Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13: [www.highcharts.com/errors/13](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13)

Comment: Try to add id= "container" to your div, instead of class.

Comment: The comment by @GrzegorzBlachliński is absolutely correct. The `renderTo` parameter always expects an ID, not a class or name. Your code should read: `<div id="container">`. Note that you could also have a class named `container` if you so wished, so long as the ID matches what the chart options expect.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I did`t notice that.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to try this:

```
var chartingOptions = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'Container_ID', //**Observation**
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions)
}
```